# Как скруглить цены! php, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как скруглить цену Если последний цифра ниже 5 то на ноль или больше 5 то на 5.
Например: 12 343 => 12 340, 12 446 => 12 445;
Можно на Php, Laravel

Comment: Разделить на 5, потом обратно умножить на 5?

Comment: `ceil($sum / $to) * $to` Нет?

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли